# How to remove CAGradientLayer from it's super layer

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, cagradientlayer

I add the layer to my view:

```
    [self.layer insertSublayer:_gradient above:_another.layer];
```

Then it doesn't seem to get removed with this, even if I call *needsDisplay* on the super layer:

```
        [_gradient removeFromSuperlayer];
```

How can I remove it?

Comment: `removeFromSuperlayer` works and doesn't need `setNeedsDisplay`.  Something else is wrong. Are you sure `_gradient` is still set (non-nil) when you call `removeFroMSuperlayer`?

Comment: yes, I have it in a if block of _gradient != nil

Comment: even so, if _gradient is nil, it won't get removed

Comment: Can you edit and share more code to show us what you are doing?  This should work.  Calling removeFromSuperlayer and then setting the layer to nil in a block of if(_gradient) has alway worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 4):

I use these and then I check to make sure it's removed:

```
// assuming there is only 1 gradientLayer this should print 1
print(parentView.layer.sublayers?.count as Any)

parentView.layer.sublayers?.removeAll() // remove everything from the parentView
gradientLayer.removeFromSuperlayer() // just to be safe

// check to see if it's in the parentView or not
if let _ = (parentView.layer.sublayers?.compactMap { $0 as? CAGradientLayer })?.first {

    print("gradientLayer has not been removed")
} else {

    print("yay it's removed")
}

// this should now print nil
print(parentView.layer.sublayers?.count as Any)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set gradient nil after remove from superlayer.It worked for me.

```
[gradient removeFromSuperlayer];
 gradient =nil;
```